# Tensorflow input dataset with varying size images

Tags: tensorflow, input

I'm trying to train a fully convolutional neural network using input images with different sizes. I can do this by looping over the training images and creating a single numpy input at each iteration i.e.,

```
for image_input, label in zip(image_data, labels):
    train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
                                         x= {"x":image_input},
                                         y=label,
                                         batch_size=1, 
                                         num_epochs=None,
                                         shuffle=False)
    fcn_classifier.train(input_fn=input_func_gen, steps=1)
```

However, in this way the model is saved and loaded after each step wasting    huge amount of resources. I have also tried creating the whole dataset at once using generators i.e.,

```
def input_func_gen():
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator=generator, 
                                  output_types=(tf.float32, tf.int32))
    dataset = dataset.batch(1)
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    return iterator.get_next()

def generator():
    filenames = ['building-d-mapimage-10-gt.png', 'building-dmapimage- 
                                                   16-gt.png']
    i = 0
    while i < len(filenames):        
        features, labels = loading.read_image_data(filenames[i])
        yield features, labels
        i += 1
        if i >= len(filenames):
            i = 0
```

And then

```
 fcn_classifier.train(input_fn=input_func_gen,
                      steps=100)
```

However, in this way the training becomes very slow and runs out of memory after first iteration, which indicates that there is something wrong with the dataset (the training runs must faster in the first case were single inputs are used). Also the shape of the features in generator are `(1, image_height, image_width,3)`  . However in the model I have to reshape them to 4-d tensors as

```
input_shape = tf.shape(input)
input = tf.reshape(input, [1, input_shape[2], input_shape[3], 3])
```

instead of `tf.reshape(input, [1, input_shape[1], input_shape[2], 3])` , which indicates that there is something weird with the dimensions of the input? In the first case I can just use the input directly without need to reshape or anything?

Comment: This isn't directly what you asked for, but I guess it's worth pointing out: what you're doing will yield poor results even if you circumvent memory issues. The convolutional kernels will not be optimized well since the input dimensions keep changing, and training using a batch size of 1 will make it very hard for gradient descent to converge. Consider resizing all images and using a batch size of at least 20.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the input. I think when training a fully-convolutional network, using varying size images with batch size 1 is a common way to go (https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonlong/long_shelhamer_fcn.pdf ) . However usually the gradients are accumulated over several batches, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this in tensorflow estimator api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to solve the problem with varying size images by changing the `input_func_gen` to following

```
def input_func_gen():
    load_path = '/path_to_images'
    data_set = 'dataset_to_use'
    image_data, labels = loading.load_image_data_grayscale(load_path,data_set)
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: 
                              itertools.zip_longest(image_data, labels),
                              output_types=(tf.float32, tf.int32),
                              output_shapes=(tf.TensorShape([1, None, None, 
                                             3]), tf.TensorShape([1, None])))
    dataset = dataset.repeat()
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    return iterator.get_next()
```