# Dealing with varying sizes inputs for TF

Tags: python, tensorflow, input, keras

I have a CNN that I built in TF, that takes `Input(shape = (1000,1000,5))`. This is because the image is a stack of 5 black-and-white images. All my samples are aerial shots of different locales, so the original images are of varying sizes (and much larger than 1000, 1000). However, TF requires that all inputs are of the same pre-determined size, so we'd decided to cut a 1000, 1000 from within all images.

This obviously loses a lot of usable information. I'm looking into ways to possibly make network with dynamic input shape, such that could take all of the original images.  I found multiple suggestions online but I find problems with each.

1. Making a separate `Input()` for each image size (say I have 2 types of sizes) which could then be convoluted into the same shape tensor. The issue is that this means one convolutional layer will be unaffected by half the observations which is bad (unless I misunderstand how the layer below works). For example:

```py
# a and b are fixed, different, image shapes
for image in inputs:
    if image.shape == a:
        x = Input(shape = a)
        x = conv2d_transpose(output_shape = (1000, 1000, 5))
    else:
        y = Input(shape = b)
        y = conv2d_transpose(output_shape = (1000, 1000, 5))
```

2. Using Eager Execution. Here all the examples I find are still for fixed input shape so I can't think of a way to use it to iterate over samples and create different inputs. I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51983716/tensorflow-input-dataset-with-varying-size-images) but the asker answered himself and I can't really say I understand the solution I'm after.
3. Resizing the images before the input. This is a particularly bad idea because resizing distorts the image and loses plenty of spatial elements, which are vital

Any *input* (I'm sorry) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason not to take the maximum possible size and zero-pad inputs? That's what the fella did in the thread you linked. Kinda tacky, but it was once common practice in NLP, and can optionally take place within convolutional layers.

Comment: That would be way too many zeros I think, the image sizes are nowhere near similar.